# get the values form into an array

Tags: java

I filtered a map with a key using mulitihashmap, but I couldn't handle the values for a particular key.

HashMap mh1 = new HashMap();

```
    HashMap m2 = new HashMap(H6.getMap());

        for(Object key : m2.keySet())
        {
            //System.out.println(key);
            if(key.toString().toLowerCase().equals(keyword))
            {
                System.out.println(" Key : "+ key + "... value : " + m2.get(key));
                String str = m2.get(key).toString();
```

`m2` is a `HashMap`. for the key, it has the values like [d1.txt, d2.txt, d3.txt, d4.txt, d5.txt, d5.txt], here I need to get the values into an array, but this str is completely a string.

the answer -->
Key : the... value : [d1.txt, d2.txt, d3.txt, d4.txt, d5.txt, d5.txt]

need to get the values in any form like array or sets only the values

Comment: `String[] arr = str.split("\\s*,\\s*");`

Comment: Why is it a string? And where does multihashmap come in?

Comment: What are the actual objects? Are they lists? Sets? Why are you using a raw HashMap? What does `H6.getMap()` return? Is it also raw?

Comment: You can split the strings by comma using regex, so it will produce an array of strings like d1.txt, d2.txt,...

Comment: here the H6.getMap() return the words and the name of the text files which contains the word, then I filtered the map with a keyword.

Comment: Actually here I want to deal with the value set, but the split method is not useable

Comment: Can you please show what your str prints exactly?

Comment: the real problem is want to filter two value set  with two keywords and want to find the intersection values from those set . like the : [d1.txt , d2. txt d5.txt]  , of : [d1.txt ,d5.txt]  answer : d1.txt, d5.txt

Comment: str prints : [d1.txt, d2.txt, d3.txt, d4.txt, d5.txt, d5.txt] but this is not actually I need. I want to get some values from that set